# App Engine, Python : Send Mail function

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sendmail

I'm using `mail.send_mail()` to send email from one address to another address.

When I run my app on localhost, i view in my log, it said :

> You are not currently sending out real email.  If you have sendmail
>   installed you can use it by using the server with --enable_sendmail

So, does it means I must enable send mail function for my server. If that true, how to enable ?

Thanks :)

Comment: @MariaZverina I'm using Windows. Does it matter to send mail function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows generally does not come with sendmail installed. You are much better off using the --smtp_host and --smtp_port options to configure your development server. Please note that these options are only required in development - once uploaded, sending mails just automagically works.

More info at:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Using_Mail

If you do not have SMTP server available to you from your ISP or your employer, you can use gmail. Settings are listed at:
http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

And to add flags to the App Engine launcher, simply double-click your instance and the use the `Extra Flags` field.
[image]

Comment: can you tell me why at log windows, I see this message : `From:... To:... Subject:...`: Normal. but after that, `Body:he syntax of the command is incorrect`. I don't think I have wrong syntax of send mail function. Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure - but it sounds like a whole new question which needs code posted ... and the logs :)

Comment: Oh. I have uploaded to server and it works fine :) But in local, I still meet this notice : `the syntax of the command is incorrect`. If you have experienced with this, tell me too :D But, maybe it doesn't affect me to much now

Comment: I know this is a pretty old answer, but I've been getting the same issue, and I don't have the GUI. I do everything from Powershell. Can you please tell me how to configure the ports from there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must enable it or you will only see the mail logged out.

see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Using_Mail

Comment: Can you tell me how to put `--enable_sendmail myapp` in Google App Engine laucher, please ?